# Independent summantion trick?

Tags: summation

We know that:
$$\sum_{k}\left(f(k)\sum_lg(l)\right)=\left(\sum_kf(k)\right)\left(\sum_lg(l)\right)$$
Since both counters are independent:
But what if we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}ke^{-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}k\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^lk^l}{l!}\right)$$
Can we use it here?

Comment: No, you cannot... And the series on the left diverges anyway.

Comment: @Fundamental t'was just an example

Comment: @ADG Wait, if that's just an example, then what's the question?

Comment: @OlivierOloa does the edit help

Comment: @JackM I was confused on using the property that's why

Comment: If the question is "can we do things with series that aren't justified by any reasoning" then the answer is **NO**.

Comment: @Fundamental OK :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have an expression of the form

$$\sum_kf(k)\sum_lg(k,l)$$

To which your factoring formula does not apply, because it requires a different form.